# NPM install with jquery giving errors? Define is undefined?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, npm

I installed jquery with NPM and I'm trying to incorporate it into an existing webpage.

In the console I see the following error: 
[image: error in console]

In my code, I have a skeleton like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang='en'>
        <head>
            <title></title>
            <link rel='stylesheet' type = 'text/css' href='css/' />
            <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
            <meta charset="UTF-8">
         </head>
         <body>
              <script type='text/javascript' src='node_modules/jquery/src/jquery.js'></script>
      <script type= 'text/javascript' src='javascript/script.js'></script>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Looking into the file itself and the error in the console, I see the following reflected both ways: 
[image: error in full detail]

I'm not very familiar with define statements but from what I've seen crawling up and down google. It looks like I need to install a bundler like webpack?

But I feel like that's unneccessary for simply adding jQuery to a project without a cdn.

Am I barking up the wrong tree? Or is this a common issue?

Comment: I think you have to be a little clearer? Why are you using NPM to install jQuery if all you want is to include it in clientside code? All you need is a static route to the file ?

Comment: I don't know much about using NPM to install resources on a webpage, but if all you need is jQuery, why are you using NPM? You can just host jQuery as a static file, or even use a CDN -- replace your jQuery script tag with this one to use Google's CDN: `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: I want to download and add jquery to the file so that I don't start a habit of just depending on cdns. I used npm because I do have node.js installed and thought it'd be a good idea to try it out and try running the project on a local http-server with node instead of just opening it in the browser. Just as practice to improve. In terms of  static route. I'm not sure what you mean

Comment: You should include a single-file version (https://jquery.com/download/) or use a module tool like Browserify or Webpack.

Comment: But NPM installs modules for the **serverside**, as in Node. When you want to include a script clientside, all you have to do is link to that script. Of course, using Node, you first have to use something to get links to static files to work, generally called static routes, and there's plenty of modules that do just that.

Comment: @HaydenSchiff  I don't want to build dependancy on using cdn's from some research I've done and some of the advice I have from the team I'm volunteering with. It seems to be viewed as bad practice. But trying to install it seems to have brought me into some strange issues I've never seen before. So I'm hoping to be pointed in the right direction. I shouldn't need webpack to run jQuery right?

Comment: The issue is your referencing a server file from a client, the node_modules folder isn't (or at least shouldn't be) publically accessible. If your using NPM you should consider a module bundler like webpack. Alternatively look at a client package manager like Bower to manage your client side dependencies.

Comment: You don't have to use the CDN; was just giving as an example. You can just download that jquery.min.js file, put it somewhere on your web server, and link to that.

Comment: So from the great feedback I've got here it seems like installing client-side and installing serverside are two different worlds. And since I'm pretty knew I was crossing streams.

Comment: Yes, download the single jQuery file, as noted above, put in a "public" folder that is accessible, and your modules folder shouldn't be accessible, then add some middleware that adds static routes, or create your own static routes, and just link to the jQuery file in the HTML, and if you did it correctly, it works. jQuery is available for use on the serverside as well, but that's different, and has nothing to do with the clientside.

Comment: jQuery server-side, middleware with static routes. yep, sounds like I've got some googling to do. I learned alot from asking this question. Thank you very much for all the helpful feedback.

Comment: Try grabbing the version from the `dist` folder, instead of `src`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `npm install jquery` is how you [use jquery with node.js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jquery#node) on the server itself.

It doesn't sound like that's what you're trying to do - rather that you want to use it on a webpage that is being served locally by your node server. To do that, [download jQuery](https://jquery.com/download/) manually and include it in your sites file structure.

```
 - index.html
 - /scripts
   - jquery-3.2.1.min.js
```

Then in your HTML reference it locally:

```
<script src="scripts/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I was being dumb and going in a cave instead of up the tree. Thank you for saving me before a bear named webpack ate me.

Comment: Of course, this doesn't work at all if you don't have the appropriate routes. Node doesn't serve up static files by default.

Comment: I didn't do any routes stuff. But installing the download directly using `script type='text/javascript' src='javascript/jquery-3.2.1.min.js'></script>` and then running my http server doesn't show the error anymore. Then again I haven't expanded on it much. Just a couple of dom traversals and event listeners. I will be doing some research into how to use routes. And I might be back soon with more questions if I get stuck